# How to set app_label in test

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am going through online tutorial for a basic Django web page and a single app.

The first and only thing I have done so far is to create the project and a single app with the sqllite database.

I have added the app to the `settings.py` file correctly.

Within the app `models.py` I have defined a single model.

The `makemigrations` command has successfully created the database for the model.

After creating the model class, I attempted to write the following test script to test the constructor of the model. This script lives in the app directory at the same level as the `models.py`.

```
from django.test import TestCase
from models import Foodie # the model
import os

# Create your tests here.
class TestModel(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_foodie(self):
        tc = Foodie()

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    unittest.main()
```

I get the error:

```
builtins.IndexError: list index out of range
File "C:\WebDev\DinnerServer\Rolls\tests.py", line 2, in <module>
from models import Foodie
File "C:\WebDev\DinnerServer\Rolls\models.py", line 7, in <module>
class Foodie(models.Model):
File "C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\Django-1.7.1-py3.3.egg\django\db\models\base.py", line 116, in >__new__
kwargs = {"app_label": package_components[app_label_index]}
```

(The app where the model resides is titled `Rolls`)
How or why is this failing and how do I set the app_label for the unit test to work?

Answer (score 1):

Basic error, the import statement is wrong.

Should be... from Rolls.models

Comment: Exactly. You should use at least one dot before `models`. Even if you want to omit the app name inside it, you can use `from __future__ import absolute_import`; `from . import models`. Or you should be in the parent directory of your app before you import the test.

Answer (score -1):

you need to add `def __str__(self):` to your `Foodie` model in `models.py`.

```
class Foodie(models.Model):
    #some fields

    def __str__(self):
        # you access to model fiels here 
        return self.label
```

Also see the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#str) may help you.

Comment: Hasan, thank you for the reply. However, this does not resolve the problem, which I think is a configuration issue of some kind.